# Formula for $\frac{1}{(n)^2}+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{1^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have this question when I try to solve some problem.

We know $\frac{1}{(n)}+\frac{1}{(n-1)}+\dots+\frac{1}{1}\to(\log n)+\lambda$, as $n\to \infty$, where $\lambda$ is a constant.
What is the value of $\frac{1}{(n)^2}+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{1^2}$?

More generally, what's
$
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1} {m^r} \frac{1} {(n-m)^{s}}$, as $n\to\infty$, where r+s is a positive natural number? (or a simpler question, when r=s.) Is there a formula for it? (Or a formula for its lower bound more accurate than $(n-1)(\frac{2}{n})^{2\max(r,s)}$ (obtained by using geometric mean being smaller than arithmetic mean?) Furthermore, what’s the case when r+s is a constant integer, or *r-s is a constant integer*?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: I see they seems to converge to a certain number, or can be expressed as a formula containing Bernoulli number

Comment: " or can be expressed as a formula containing Bernoulli number ", and how do you see that?

Comment: Perhaps I misread it, it says, "a simple expression in terms of the Bernoulli numbers whenever s is a positive even integer." in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is the [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#:%7E:text=The%20sum%20of%20the%20series,announced%20this%20discovery%20in%201735.). We have $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigg[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} \Bigg] = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

And what you mentioned in your post,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bigg[ \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log(n) \Bigg] = \gamma $$
Where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\LARGE\left.a\right)}$

With the [Abel-Plana Formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2) and
$\ds{\vartheta_{n - 1} \in \pars{0,1}}$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k^{2}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{n - 1}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}^{2}} +
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,{1 \over \pars{k + 1}^{2}}}_{\ k\ =\ 0} +
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,{1 \over \pars{k + 1}^{2}}}_{\ k\ =\ n - 1}
\\[2mm] &
+\ \underbrace{4\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over
\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{2}\pars{\expo{2\pi x} - 1}}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{{\pi^{2} \over 6} - {3 \over 2}}}\ +\
\sum_{s = 1}^{m}{B_{2s} \over \pars{2s}!}
\bracks{-\,{\pars{2s}! \over n ^{2s + 1}}}
\\[2mm] &
+ 2\pars{-1}^{m}\pars{2m + 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\Im\pars{\bracks{n + \ic\vartheta_{n - 1}x}^{-2m - 2}}\,
{x^{2m} \over \expo{2\pi x} - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{1 - {1 \over n}} + {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2n^{2}} +
\pars{{\pi^{2} \over 6} - {3 \over 2}} -
\sum_{s = 1}^{m}{B_{2s} \over n^{2s + 1}}
\\[2mm] & 
+ 2\pars{-1}^{m}\pars{2m + 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\Im\pars{\bracks{n + \ic\vartheta_{n - 1}x}^{-2m - 2}}\,
{x^{2m} \over \expo{2\pi x} - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{{\pi^{2} \over 6} - {1 \over n} + {1 \over 2n^{2}} +
\sum_{s = 1}^{m}{B_{2s} \over n^{2s + 1}}}
\\[2mm] &
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{+\ 2\pars{-1}^{m}\pars{2m + 1}}
\\[1mm] & \bbox[10px,#ffd]{\left. \phantom{=}\times\int_{0}^{\infty}
\Im\pars{\bracks{n + \ic\vartheta_{n - 1}x}^{-2m - 2}}
{x^{2m} \over \expo{2\pi x} - 1}
\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\, \vartheta_{n - 1}\ \in\ \pars{0,1}}}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\LARGE\left.b\right)}$

By using a
[Zeta function identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8):
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k^{\color{red}{2}}} & =
\zeta\pars{2} - \,{n^{1 - \color{red}{2}} \over \color{red}{2} - 1} +
\color{red}{2}\int_{n}^{\infty}
{x - \left\lfloor\,{x}\,\right\rfloor \over x^{\color{red}{2} + 1}}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi^{2} \over 6} - {1 \over n} +
2\sum_{k = n}^{\infty}\int_{k}^{k +1}{x - k \over x^{3}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi^{2} \over 6} - {1 \over n} +\
\underbrace{\sum_{k = n}^{\infty}{1 \over k\pars{k + 1}^{2}}}
_{\ds{1 + n - n^{2}\,\Psi\, '\pars{n} \over n^{2}}}\quad
\pars{~\Psi\, ':\ Trigamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{{\pi^{2} \over 6} - {1 \over n} + {1 \over 2n^{2}} -
{1 \over 6n^{3}} + {1 \over 30n^{5}} + \mrm{O}\pars{1 \over n^{6}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$S'=\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} < \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k(k-1)}= \sum_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)$$
By telescopic summation, we get $$S'<1-\frac{1}{n}.$$
Hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}< 2-\frac{1}{n}$$
The sum of yhe infinite version of this series is well known as $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, we have that

$$(n-1)^{1-\max(r,s)} \leq \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m^r}\frac{1}{(n-m)^s} \leq (n-1)^{1-\min(r,s)}$$

WLOG, we can assume $s \leq r$ (since the sum is symmetric when summing backwards). So we see that the sum only exists when $s\geq 1$

Comment: Would you tell me how we get this inequality?

Comment: @CharlieChang take the smallest and largest terms then multiply by the number of terms ($n-1$ terms) Actually you made me realize the smallest term may not be correct. But the upper bound still gives a correct condition for convergence

Comment: I guess you mean the lower bound is $(n-1)(\frac{2}{n})^{2\max(r,s)} \approx 2(\frac{2}{n})^{2\max(r,s)-1}$

Answer (score 1):

There is an asymptotic expansion in terms of the Bernoulli numbers:
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^2 }}}  \sim \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6} - \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{{2n^2 }} - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{2k} }}{{n^{2k + 1} }}} 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. This shows how the limit $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is approached.

Comment: The last series $\displaystyle{\tt diverges}$ because $\displaystyle\left\vert B_{2k}\right\vert \sim
4\pi\mathrm{e}^{1/2}\left(k \over \pi\mathrm{e}\right)^{2k + 1/2}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes, asymptotic expansions usually diverge (convergent ones are boring).